# If $s$ is the sum of all distinct real roots of $f(x)$, then find correct option

Tags: calculus

Consider the polynomial $f(x) = 1 + 2x + 3x^2 + 4x^3$. Let $s$ be the sum of all distinct real roots of $f(x)$ and let $t =|s|$. The area bounded by the curve $y = f(x)$ and the lines $x = 0, y = 0$ and $x = t$, lies in which of the the following interval:

(A)$(0.75,3)$

(B)$(0,\frac{21}{64})$

(C)$(\frac{21}{64},\frac{11}{16})$

(D)$(9,10)$

As $f'(x)>0$ for all $x \in R$, hence $f(x)$ is an increasing function which equation will have only one real root.

As $f(-1) \cdot f(0)<0$, root lies in $x \in (-1,0)$ but I am not getting how to proceed further. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Suppose you were able to find out what $t$ was. What would the area bounded by $y=f(x)$, $x=0$, $y=0$, and $x=t$ be? (If you can answer this, you should probably put it into the problem statement as well.)

Answer (score 1):

Using what you've found already, we have $0\leq t \leq 1$. It's easy to get the inflexion point of $f(x)$ at $x= -1/4$, so we know that $f(x)$ is concave up in the interval from $0$ to $1$.  $f(0)=1$ and $f(1) = 10$, so the area you want is
less than the trapezoid above the interval $0<x<1$ and under the line through $(0,1)$ and $(1,10)$ which is $11/2$.  So that eliminates choice D.  It remains to argue that the area has to be at least $0.75$, which makes choice A the right answer.

To that end:  $f(-1/2)$ is positive, so $t>1/2$. $f^{\prime}(0) = 2$ and $f$ is
concave up $0<x<1/2$, so the graph of $f$ lies above the line $y = 2x+1$.  The area under this line between $x=0$ and $x=1/2$ is $3/4$, so the area you want is larger.